# An example of a continuous real function on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying a certain condition and that does not satisfy other conditions in a paper

Tags: calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I am reading [this](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPC_1996__13_5_567_0.pdf) paper and the authors stated

> it is easy to construct examples of $Q(x)$ for which none of the above criteria are satisfied and condition $(Q)$ holds.

on page $569$.

The $(Q)$ condition is

> $Q(x) \geq 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ and there exist some points $a^1, \cdots, a^k$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$ such that $Q(a^j)$ are strict maximums and satisfy
> $$Q(a^j) = Q_{\text{max}} \equiv \ \text{Max} \ \{ Q(x) ; x \in \mathbb{R}^N \} > 0, j = 1, \cdots, k.$$

The other conditions are in the final of the page $568$.

I am having difficult to define such function $Q$, then I would like to receive some intuition about how to construct it. All I could think in order to define such function is to construct a function like this

[image]

such that $Q$ behaves periodically as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$.

Thanks in advance!